# How to get the difference between documents

Tags: batch-file

Everyday, a document is created automatically named articles.txt.

I have to make several changes to the document.
After the changes made the document is named articles_Final + date.txt 
As example :  `articles_Final_2016_01_07.txt`

The documents are then moved to a directory ". \ HISTO \ FINAL".

I have to compare the two last document created and to write the difference in a new document  result.txt

I show you my code for findind the two last documents

```
@echo off & cls
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Dossier=.\HISTO\Final"
set /a "n=0, limit=2"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D /O-D /T:W "%Dossier%\*.*"') do (
   echo "%%a"
   2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
)
:break
pause
exit
```

And le code who compare the two document
Here, I write the name of them but i would like to find the way to write automaticly the result of my first code

```
findstr /v /g:articles_Final_2016_01_04.txt  articles_Final_2016_02_04.txt  >result.txt
```

Comment: What about using `fc /L` for comparison?

Comment: Just type `fc /?` iton a comman prompt window to fid out how to use the `fc` command which is an internal command for comparing two files; `fc /L "file1.txt" "file2.txt"` compares two text files (`/L` forces text comparison); the output shows all the differences between the files, or `No differences encountered.` in case the files are considered equal...

Comment: OK aschipfl. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the final solution

```
@echo off
cls
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Dossier=.\HISTO\FINAL"
set /a "n=0, limit=2"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D /O-D /T:W "%Dossier%\*.*"') do (
   echo "%%a"

   set "file[!n!]=%%a"

   2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
)
:break

set file
    findstr /v /g:%Dossier%\%file[0]% %Dossier%\%file[1]% >>difference.txt
    ::fc /L %Dossier%\%file[0]% %Dossier%\%file[1]% >>difference.txt

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
cls
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Dossier=.\HISTO\Final"
set /a "n=0, limit=2"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D /O-D /T:W "%Dossier%\*.*"') do (
   echo "%%a"

   set "file[!n!]=%%a"

   2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
)
:break

set file

echo findstr /v /g:%Dossier%\%file[0]% %Dossier%\%file[1]% 

pause
exit
```

(untried)

The `findstr` command will just be `echo`ed - you'd need to check it and redirect the output.

the `set file` command is simply a way of displaying all variables that start with `file`.

Comment: Thank Magoo for your help